# CSS pure-control-group

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have this controls in my JSP, the problem is that when I focus in 1 input text all the text dissapear

```
<div class="pure-control-group">
     <label for="emailInput" id="emailLabel">
          Email
     </label>
     <input id="email" name="email" type="text" value=""/>
</div>
```

and I don't know how to fix it

[image]

Here the description waas filled until I put the cursor on it

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a testing case?? The fields might get emptied in many ways.

Comment: Sounds like you have a js plugin that is removing the text

Answer (score 0):

you can use the focus css selector to change the color of the input field so the text is visible.

```
input {
    color:black;
}

input:focus {
    color:black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`onfocus` & `onblur`

`<input onfocus="if(this.value == 'Description'){this.value = '';}" type="text" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value='Description';}" id="name" value="Description" />`